# Flexbox: Header, centered body and sticky footer overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Update** This has been solved thanks to LGSon's comment below **[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRKOoz?editors=1100)**

I am trying to setup a layout much like the Holy grail. The difference here is that I am looking for a dynamically sized "Content" section to be vertically and horizontally centered.

I have been able to get this working (*for large displays*) with flexbox: **[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/morganrowse/pen/qjYeyM)**

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
.content p {
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.header, .footer {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    Header
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>I am the content</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

The problem is that if the "Content" section is too large, or the view is too small, the overflow wont kick in until the div is more than 100% vertical not (100% height - the header and footer heights)

I am trying to make it so that when there is overlap, that the whole page will scroll and not only have a scrollbar within the "Content section".

Comment: Do you know that the header and footer scroll alongside the rest of the page? Surely this isn't the desired result...

Comment: is this the expected end result? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRKOoz?editors=1100

Comment: Hi @JamesDouglas, Currently not looking for sticky headers and footers unless the content is too small for the view like in the desktop screenshot linked above. I think bootstrap terminology for this is [Fixed](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) which I am not looking for.

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for the magic, that is exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your `html, body` rule to this

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and then add this new rule

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

and then change from `height: calc(100% - 120px);` to `flex-grow: 1;` in your `content` rule it will work as you asked for.

The trick here is to make your `body` a flex container, and then, by setting the `content` to `flex-grow: 1` it will fill the remaining space when the content is smaller, and the `min-height: 100vh` will allow it to properly grow higher than the viewport when the content is bigger.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRKOoz?editors=1100)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.content p {
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.header, .footer {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    Header
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>I am the content</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

---

And if someone want to enable the `content` to scroll instead of the whole page, change the `body` rule to `height: 100vh` and  add `overflow: auto` to the `content` rule

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeErQB)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: auto;
}

.content p {
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.header, .footer {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    Header
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>I am the content</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After using `position: fixed;` on the header and footer, my syggestion is to:

1. remove the opaque background colours, and replace them with *non* opaque ones that look exactly the same (this I have already done)
2. remove the background colour for the article, and give the `html, body` the background-color instead
3. use `background-color` instead of `background` in this case:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #7FFF7F;
  text-align: center;

}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF7F7F;
}

.content {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.content p {
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7F7FFF;
}

.header,
.footer {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    Header
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>I am the content</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/bRKGom)